# How to debug app when it's killed

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

My app has a bug on certain activities: when it restarts (when it's killed and then opened again with multitasker), it crashes. I assume it has something to do with my singleton, but I'm not sure. I'd like to pinpoint the problem, but I can't debug since the debugger stops when I kill the application (I'm using `adb shell am kill <package-name>`).

Does anyone know how I can debug this problem? (Or give me a hint what my problem might be for that matter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use DDMS (Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS) to capture the stack trace, etc.. after your kill and restart our app.

(FYI: It is already installed along with the rest of the Android toolset)

While it is not going to allow you to debug you app via VS/XS, it can help you pin the area of your app that is the cause. From there I would add logging around the trouble area (i.e. the old-fashion `printf` style debugging)

[image]

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html

To launch from Visual Studio:

[image]

From Xamarin Studio:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. By the way, I just discovered you can open DDMS from Visual Studio by clicking [this button](http://i.imgur.com/m5Elmin.png).

Comment: @FrederickEskens Thanks, I added that link into the answer along with how to launch form Xamarin Studio

Comment: Another note: make sure you're running VS/XS as administrator. This took me way too lang to figure out.

Answer (score 13):

You can add the following code to the onCreate() method of your main activity:

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

This will pause your app till a debugger is attached to the process.

Then :

- Run your app
- Put your app in background (say, with the home button)
- Kill the process or use an app like [MemoryPump](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fabsimilian.memorypump) to fill the RAM and have your app killed by Android
- Switch back to your app with the multitask pan  (the app will start and wait for the debugger)
- Attach your android studio debugger to you app (icon in the Android Studio toolbar somewhere between the 'run app' icon and the 'stop application' icon)
- Debug your app

Answer (score 1):

If you use your singleton class to preload some data the instance will be destroyed when you kill your application so you will have to reload the data that your singleton needs.

You can also add [Raygun](https://app.raygun.io/) which will catch all exceptions and send it to server where you will be able to view the exception details.

You can get it from nuget: [Mindscape.Raygun4Net 5.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mindscape.Raygun4Net/)

Comment: I assumed that so I put `if`s in the onCreate an onResume that check if the singleton is `null`. If it is, it should just go back to the main activity. But it still crashes.