# How to close an app and test its background processes with ADB shell

Tags: java, android, shell, android-studio, adb

Trying to close an application and monitor it's background processes on debugger, is this possible with adb shell?

Comment: hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763477/how-to-debug-app-when-its-killed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to check the app is running-

Below command gives all running process on your device.

```
adb shell ps
```

In case above command doesn't show all running process, use below command.

```
adb shell ps -A
```

grep your app by giving app name or any part of your app process name.

```
adb shell ps | grep <app/process name>
```

Get the pid(the number in second column of above command's output) of your running app from output of above command and kill the app by its process id

```
adb shell kill -9 <app pid>
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a lot. I was beginning to think it wasn't really possible.

Comment: Although I'm getting a permission error when attempting to kill the application. Also, after I kill the application how can I monitor it's background processes?

Comment: Can you post error you are getting ? may be you need root permissions to kill that app ? what do you meant by 'its' background process ? if you killed the parent process(your app) all will be killed. if you want kill all instances of it you can do `killall <processname>`